# Get enum values from bit that represenst combination of bit values?

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation

I have an enum type like this:

```
  public enum MyEnum: ulong
  {
    All = 0UL,
    Func1 = 1UL,
    Func2 = 4UL,
    Func3 = 8UL,
    Func4 = 16UL,
    Func5 = 32UL,
    Func6 = 256UL,
    // and so on...
    // but notice this is the order, on purpose
  }
```

Now, I would like to determine if it's possible, if user enters for example 9 which should be a combination of Func1 and Func3, how to get Func1 and Func3 from 9 in to the list for example. I've search this web site for answers but without luck. I need this in .net 3.5. If by some chance this is repeated question or there is similar thank you for pointing it out to me. Assume I cannot change them to be in order like 1 2 4 8 16...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the value you're querying is `myUlong`, use this:

```
MyEnum myValue = (MyEnum)myUlong;
var result = 
    ((MyEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))).Where(n => (n & myValue) != 0);
//that will get you your result
```

Comment: Not quite, you want `n & myValue != 0`.

Comment: Well look at what `Enum.GetValues` will return - would *any* of them be 9?

Comment: I was able to solve it by putting braces, like this (n & myValue) != 0. Guys thanks for your help and appreciate you effective response. Thank you very much. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can either check (n & myValue) != 0 or (n & myValue) == n